# When a widget in Flutter is clicked, the other widget on the same screen does not update correctly and the if operator does not work correctly

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

As can be seen on the screen below, when the user clicks on the relevant day in the calendar, the card widget below should be updated with the information entered by the "+" button below and display it on the screen. (With the "+" button, the modal bottom sheet is opened and information is entered. This information is kept in the 'items' list).

[image]

However, screen only updates after clicking submit on the "modal bottom sheet". Clicking on the dates does not update and gives a null error.

[image]
[image]

Because when I click on dates it skips the "if (itemIndexToDate() == null)" part.

[image]

I added an iconbutton to the upper right corner of the board for an update attempt and wanted it to call the 'setstate' function every time it was clicked. When I do this the error goes away and the "if (itemIndexToDate() == null)" part of the code is read.

[image]

I haven't been able to resolve this issue for a week and I need support. How can I solve it? I am attaching the codes below. Thank you.

**home.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:lessonlearned/models/items.dart';
import 'package:lessonlearned/widgets/bottom_nav_bar.dart';
import 'package:lessonlearned/widgets/date_picker_controller.dart';
import 'package:lessonlearned/widgets/date_picker_widget.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Items _itemsController = Get.put(Items());
    final DatePickerController _showedDateController =
        Get.put(DatePickerController());

    /// Find related Item index in the Items list according to registration date using loop formula.
    int? itemIndexToDate() {
      for (var i = 0; i < _itemsController.items.length; i++) {
        if (_itemsController.items[i].registrationDate.toString() ==
            _showedDateController.showedDate.toString()) {
          return i;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }
      return null;
    }

    //ValueNotifier<int?> _counter = ValueNotifier<int?>(itemIndexToDate());

    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text('Home',
            style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor)),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        top: true,
        bottom: true,
        left: true,
        right: true,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14.0),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(
                  greeting().toString(),
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const DatePickerWidget(),
            const SizedBox(height: 5),
            const Divider(),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            //Assessment of the day
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14.0),
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: const Text(
                  "Assessment of the day",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            if (itemIndexToDate() == null)
              Card(
                elevation: 6,
                color: Colors.white,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                shape: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                child: const SizedBox(
                  height: 200,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text("empty"),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            else
              Stack(
                children: [
                  Card(
                    elevation: 6,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    shape: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 200,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                const Icon(Icons.sentiment_very_satisfied,
                                    color: Colors.green, size: 25),
                                const SizedBox(width: 5),
                                Flexible(
                                  child: Obx(
                                    () => Text(
                                      _itemsController
                                          .items[itemIndexToDate()!].workedDesc,
                                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Obx(
                              () => SizedBox(
                                height: 20,
                                child: ListView.separated(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                  itemBuilder:
                                      (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                    return Container(
                                      child: Text(
                                          _itemsController
                                              .items[itemIndexToDate()!]
                                              .goodSkills[index],
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.white)),
                                      color: Colors.green,
                                    );
                                  },
                                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
                                      const SizedBox(width: 10),
                                  itemCount: _itemsController
                                      .items[itemIndexToDate()!]
                                      .goodSkills
                                      .length,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            //SizedBox(width: 5),
                            const Divider(),
                            //SizedBox(width: 5),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                const Icon(Icons.sentiment_neutral,
                                    color: Colors.red, size: 25),
                                const SizedBox(width: 5),
                                Flexible(
                                  child: Obx(
                                    () => Text(
                                      _itemsController.items[itemIndexToDate()!]
                                          .notWorkedDesc,
                                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 20,
                              child: ListView(
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                children: [
                                  SizedBox(
                                      width: 20,
                                      height: 2,
                                      child: Container(color: Colors.green)),
                                  SizedBox(
                                      width: 20,
                                      height: 2,
                                      child: Container(color: Colors.red)),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: const Alignment(0.98, 0.5),
                    child: IconButton(
                      iconSize: 20,
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            //Daily Quotes
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14.0),
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: const Text(
                  "Daily quotes",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Card(
              elevation: 4,
              color: Colors.white,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              shape: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  borderSide: BorderSide.none),
              child: Container(
                height: 80,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: const MyBottomNavBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

**date_picker_widget.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:lessonlearned/widgets/date_picker_controller.dart';
import 'package:scrollable_positioned_list/scrollable_positioned_list.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import '../pages/home/view/home.dart';

class DatePickerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const DatePickerWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  DatePickerWidgetState createState() => DatePickerWidgetState();
}

class DatePickerWidgetState extends State<DatePickerWidget> {
  DateTime firstDate = DateTime(2022, 1, 1); // initial date

  DateTime lastDate =
      DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 10)); // final date

  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();

  String? showedDate; // to tracking date

  int currentDateSelectedIndex =
      DateTime.now().difference(DateTime(2022, 1, 1)).inDays;
//For Horizontal Date

  // ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: ); //Scroll Controller for ListView

  List<String> listOfMonths = [
    "Jan",
    "Feb",
    "Mar",
    "Apr",
    "May",
    "Jun",
    "Jul",
    "Aug",
    "Sep",
    "Oct",
    "Nov",
    "Dec"
  ]; //List Of Months

  List<String> listOfDays = [
    "Mon",
    "Tue",
    "Wed",
    "Thu",
    "Fri",
    "Sat",
    "Sun"
  ]; //List of Days

  final DatePickerController _showedDateController =
      Get.put(DatePickerController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 90,
      child: ScrollablePositionedList.separated(
        separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return const SizedBox(width: 10);
        },
        itemCount: lastDate.difference(firstDate).inDays,
        initialScrollIndex: currentDateSelectedIndex - 2,

        //controller: scrollController,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return index <= DateTime.now().difference(DateTime(2022, 1, 1)).inDays
              ? InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    currentDateSelectedIndex = index;
                    selectedDate = firstDate.add(Duration(days: index));
                    showedDate = DateFormat('dd.MM.yyyy').format(selectedDate);
                    _showedDateController.changeshowedDate(showedDate);

                    setState(() {});

                    //print(showedDate);
                    //print(_showedDateController.showedDate);
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: 80,
                    width: 60,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        color: currentDateSelectedIndex == index
                            ? Colors.blue
                            : Colors.white),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          listOfMonths[
                                  firstDate.add(Duration(days: index)).month -
                                      1]
                              .toString(),
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 10,
                              color: currentDateSelectedIndex == index
                                  ? Colors.white
                                  : Colors.black),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 3,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          firstDate.add(Duration(days: index)).day.toString(),
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              color: currentDateSelectedIndex == index
                                  ? Colors.white
                                  : Colors.black),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 3,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          listOfDays[
                                  firstDate.add(Duration(days: index)).weekday -
                                      1]
                              .toString(),
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 10,
                              color: currentDateSelectedIndex == index
                                  ? Colors.white
                                  : Colors.grey),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    null;
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: 80,
                    width: 60,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        color: Colors.grey[200]),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          listOfMonths[
                                  firstDate.add(Duration(days: index)).month -
                                      1]
                              .toString(),
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 10, color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 3,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          firstDate.add(Duration(days: index)).day.toString(),
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 3,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          listOfDays[
                                  firstDate.add(Duration(days: index)).weekday -
                                      1]
                              .toString(),
                          style:
                              const TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.grey),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it really skipped or is it because your function returns null ? Actually, your method

```
int? itemIndexToDate() {
      for (var i = 0; i < _itemsController.items.length; i++) {
        if (_itemsController.items[i].registrationDate.toString() ==
            _showedDateController.showedDate.toString()) {
          return i;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
```

is weird because it is a loop, but it will check your assertion for `i=0` only, because of your first `return null;`. You can add break points in this method to check that. But I think you wanted something like this instead:

```
int? itemIndexToDate() {
      for (var i = 0; i < _itemsController.items.length; i++) {
        if (_itemsController.items[i].registrationDate.toString() ==
            _showedDateController.showedDate.toString()) {
          return i;
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried your code but it didn't worked. Issue is same.